# How to compile java files into directory at the same level as java files?

Tags: java, compilation, javac

I have very simple case. In folder `D://redbacktree` I have two files `.java`.

I want to compile them into folder `D://redbacktree/bin`.

What I tried is :

```
javac -d bin *.java
```

This created folder `redblacktree` inside `bin` folder and put `.class` files into 
`D://redbacktree/bin/redblacktree/`

But I don't want `javac` to create `redblacktree` folder inside `bin` folder.

How to compile and run this correctly?

Comment: Does your java file hava a package declaration (I guess it does since the folder is created). If you want all files in a "root" then leave out the package declaration. This is not "good form" though - but it will fix your "problem". Have you considered using a build tool?

Comment: You are right. Now I compiled my `.java` files into `D://redbacktree/redblacktree/` folder. How to run class file if it still contains package declaration?

Comment: Made comment into answer instead.

Comment: If your classes are declared in a package 'redblacktree' you are wrong in your desire for the .class files not to be in a directory 'redblacktree'. The Java compiler is doing the correct thing here. The real problem here is that the .java files should be in such a directory too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll create an answer from my comment instead.
So first off; if you have package declarations (which is good practice to organize your code and modules) your files will end up in a folder structure matching your package structure.

I'd suggest reading the man pages for `javac` and `java`to see all the flags and options. I'd also suggest using some kind of build tool and follow the java "convention" of how to organize your source and class files. Read more [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

[Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) or [Buildr](http://buildr.apache.org/) are three examples of build tools for Java.

Too "fix" your current problem you can run your compiled java classes using:

```
java -cp bin redblacktree.<name of your class>
```

i.e you need to use the fully qualified name (package path + class name) when telling java which class to run. Also `-cp` specifies the (root-)classpath, where your compiled classes can be found.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your java files have a package declaration?

```
package redbacktree;
```

The compiler creates a separate folder for each package. You could try to use the default package (i.e. omit the package declration completely), although it is not a good practice to use the default package.

Comment: Yes, it does contain package declaration.